# Angular proxy - 404 Error on Api after build app and upload on server

Tags: angular, proxy

I'm facing a problem with proxying to external api after I build an app and upload it on server.

Start from beggining:

1. In my `proxy.config.json` I put below configuration:

`{
    "/api/*": {
      "target": "http://api.example.com/api/",
      "secure": false,
      "logLevel": "debug",
      "pathRewrite": {
        "^/api": ""
      },
      "changeOrigin": true
    }
}`

1. I'm calling this api using below function in my.service.ts:

   `loginUser(userName:string,Password:string){
       let loginInfo = {Email:userName,Password:Password}
               return this.http.post('/api/authenticate',loginInfo,{headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json-patch+json'},responseType:'text'})
           .pipe(map(data => {
               this.currentUser = data
               this.isLoggedIn = true
               return true
           }))
           .pipe(catchError(err => {
               this.errorResponse.push({status:err.status,statusText:err.statusText,message:err.message})
               return this.errorResponse
           }))
   }`
2. When I call this from `localhost` it works like a charm. In the browser console I get:
   `http://localhost:4200/api/authenticate`
3. But when I build the app and serve it on my hosting server I get error `POST http://example.com/api/authenticate 404 (Not Found)` and it post to this URL -> `http://example.com/api/authenticate`

   ### Heading

Some details about app:

- Frontend app is serve on `www.example.com`
- All api's are on `api.example.com`
- On localhost it work on hosting server it does not

Please let me know if you need more details I will edit this post to add those information.

UPDATE:

`angular.json` file:

`{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "my-app-name": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/my-app-name",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/pink-bluegrey.css",
              "src/styles.css",
              "src/styles/bootstrap-4.4.1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"

            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "my-app-name:build",
            "proxyConfig": "proxy.config.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "my-app-name:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "my-app-name:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/pink-bluegrey.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "my-app-name:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "my-app-name:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "my-app-name"
}`

Answer (score 0):

try to add the **proxyConfig** option to the serve target in angular.json

```
"architect": {
  "serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
    "options": {
      "browserTarget": "your-application-name:build",
      "proxyConfig": "proxy.config.json"
    },
```

[see more](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md)

Comment: entire file, add in your post to better explain the problem, because your problem depends in some config in angular.json

Comment: Added to my post

Comment: you added proxyConfig in "serve" that means in development mode , you should add it in "build" and "test", this is an example  [angular.json](https://github.com/raphaelkoszalka/hotel-front/blob/2504ea174355871cfbd1228742e0a96f85dee6dc/angular.json)